# Angular 4 - Component variables still undefined even within ".then" in Promises

Tags: angular, angular2-services

It's very strange, the variables remain undefined even when values are assigned within `.then` method for Promises.

```
  this.parentService.getParent(this.fatherId)
  .then(parents => { 
                      if(parents != null && parents.id)
                      {
                          **this.parents = parents ;**
```

> ```
>                         console.log(JSON.stringify(parents));
> ```

```
                          this.motherId = parents.mother.idCardNumber;
                          this.child.fatherId = this.fatherId;
                          this.child.motherId = parents.mother.idCardNumber;
                      }else
                        {
                          this.initParents();
                        }
                    });

}
```

I do expect variable this.parent to have the same parents values when service getParent returns the parent promise.

Right now, the html template is being async filled, but component variable, this.parent still undefined and I dont really understand why.
 **console.log(JSON.stringify(parents))** prints an empty JSON array:

> {"address":{},"contacts":{},"father":{"address":{},"contacts":{}},"mother":{"address":{},"contacts":{}}}

parent.service.ts:

getParent(id : string): Promise
  {

```
this.parent = new Parent(new Person(), new Person());

console.log("Current Parent: " + this.parent.id);
  //this.parent.id = "1";
    this.db.list<Parent>('/Parents').snapshotChanges().subscribe(
           parents => {
              //console.log(childs);

              for(let i = 0 ; i < parents.length ; i ++)
              {

                console.log(parents[i].payload.val());

                //let mparent = parents[i].payload.val();

                  this.assignParent(parents[i].payload.val(), id);                      

              }
            });

    return Promise.resolve(this.parent);
```

}

```
    assignParent(parent: Parent, id : string): void
{

    if(parent != null)
        {
          console.log("The ParentId:  " + id + "  Local: " + parent.id );

            if(parent.id == id)
            {
                //let mparent = parent;
                //this.copyChild(child);
                //this.parent = Object.assign({}, parent);

                //console.log("JSON:  " + JSON.stringify(this.child));
                this.parent.id = parent.id;

                this.helper.copyPerson(this.parent.father, parent.father);
                this.helper.copyPerson(this.parent.mother, parent.mother);


                //this.parent = parent;
                console.log("YES:  " + this.parent.id);


            }

        }


}
```

Comment: try to log `JSON.stringify(parents.data)`

Comment: can we see the getParent Service Function, and its return value?  Does the return value come back with data?

Comment: JSON.stringify(parents.id) gives undefined.

Comment: Frasi78, I have posted the method on parent.service, be aware that very same code worked before updating angularFire to Version 5. Value is retrieved, but it seems to me that it does not preserve or something. Well I dont really know what's happening, it messed up my whole project.

Comment: @Jorgehel, I'm not too familiar with angularFire, but could this have to do with you resolving this.parent (which is I am assuming a public variable), but setting the assignment separately?  Have you tried this: return Promise.resolve(this.assignParent(parents[i].payload.val(), id)); or something similar?

Comment: @Farasi78, I have done it separately to cast parent[i].payload.val() to Parent type and access properties, like filtering by id and get the parent I'm looking for. return as you stated, gives just the same result. Well, thanks for your feedback anyway...I have to deep check what's wrong with that. Inside .then it should give the value, object...assigned and not an undefined. I suspect of those snapshots (angularFire) being wrongly set up in the service.